# How to find the minimum no of bits required to express the filter coefficients in fixed point format from Histogram plot?

Tags: matlab, digital-filters, analog-to-digital, quantization, histogram

I have designed a filter in MATLAB and now I have to convert the filter coefficient in fixed point format from floating point format. For that my professor asked me to find histogram first and then find how many bits I required for fixed point representation. But I am not sure how to find that from histogram plot.

Comment: a histogram of *what* ??

Comment: Histogram of filter coefficient may be. I am not sure

Comment: then with what distribution of values of the parameters (e.g. resonant frequency and Q) that determine the coefficients.  if your prof wants you to determine the range of the coefficients so that you can set a range for your fixed-point representation, that can be done with math.  is the filter you're designing IIR?  second-order IIR?

Comment: FIR. Filter has been designed. I know other methods to convert fixed point. But my prof wants to find it from Histogram plot. He wants to know how many minimum bits are required so that there is not significant difference in filter response after fixed point conversion